# How to set Everything as default for search scope

Tags: search, jquery, scope

is there way to set **Everything** as default Search Scope to Search Box via **jQuery**. 
So when someone just enter text and hit search it will search in **SearchCenter** and not in **osssearchresults.aspx.**

And to remove This site completely.. 
I know that there is the way to do that via site settings > under site collection administration > search settings but there are a lot of Site Collections and sites and I don't want to do that manually for all of them.

ps. On picture is selected Conversations but I need Everything...

[image: Search Dropdown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by replacing text in search text box and replacing keydown function search action...
Here is code:

```
       //Function to Change default behavior of SearchBox
       function FixSearchBox() {
           var theSearchBox = $('#SearchBox input');
           var defaultSearchText = "Search this site";
           var preferredSearchText = "Search everything";
           var SearchCenterUrl = "/sites/search/"; 

           theSearchBox.val(preferredSearchText);
           theSearchBox.attr("title", preferredSearchText);
           theSearchBox.blur(function () {

               if ($(this).val().indexOf(defaultSearchText) > -1)
                   $(this).val(preferredSearchText);
           });
           theSearchBox.focus(function () {
               $(this).val("");
           });

           $("#SearchBox input").attr("onkeypress", "");
           $("#SearchBox input").keydown(function (e) {
               if (e.keyCode == "13") {
                   ProcessClick($("#SearchBox a[title='Search']"), preferredSearchText, SearchCenterUrl);
               }
           });
       }

       //Function for starting search
       function ProcessClick(button,preferredSearchText, SearchCenterUrl) {
           var query = $("#SearchBox input").val().replace(preferredSearchText,"*");
           var selectedSearch = $("div.ms-qSuggest-hListItem").text();

           if (query.length < 2 || query == '*') {
               document.location.href = SearchCenterUrl +"/Pages/results.aspx?k=*";
           }
           else {
               switch (selectedSearch) {
                   case "People":
                       document.location.href = SearchCenterUrl + "/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k=" + query;
                       break;
                   case "Conversations":
                       document.location.href = SearchCenterUrl + "/Pages/conversationresults.aspx?k=" + query;
                       break;
                   case "Video":
                       document.location.href = SearchCenterUrl + "/Pages/videoresults.aspx?k=" + query;
                   default:
                       document.location.href = SearchCenterUrl + "/Pages/results.aspx?k=" + query;
                       break;
               }
           }
       }
```

PS. I added also a thing to search for '*' if you just click on search action (search icon).

to remove "Search this Site" from drop down I used css:

```
       div.ms-qSuggest-listItem:last-child
       {
         display:none;
       }
```